# Selective polygon visualization around a specified location using geospatial analysis

Tags: python, gis, polygon, folium

I have a shapefile containing multiple polygons, as illustrated in this example:

[image]

My objective is to display only the polygons that encompass a specific location, rather than visualizing all of them.

To achieve this, I initiated an approach by generating a shape, either a circle or a rectangle, and attempted to constrain or extract the polygons within that shape.

Here is the code snippet I employed using Python libraries such as `folium`, `geopandas`, and `shapely`:

```py
import folium
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point

# Define the center location
center_location = (48.8566, 2.3522)

# Create a folium map centered at the defined location
m = folium.Map(location=center_location, zoom_start=12)

# Set the radius of the circle
circle_radius = 5000

# Define the center point as a shapely Point
center_point = Point(center_location)

# Create a circle shape around the center point
circle = center_point.buffer(circle_radius)

# Filter polygons that intersect with the circle
polygons_in_circle = gdf[gdf.geometry.intersects(circle)]

# Display the resulting polygons
polygons_in_circle
```

Could you kindly assist me with refining this approach?

Comment: It is unclear to me from the post what the question is. You could also consider clipping if you're looking for an alternative. https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.clip.html